# Speed of curve after projection onto tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\alpha$ be a unit speed curve in $S$, $p$ be a point in $\alpha$ (say $p=\alpha(s_0)$) and $\beta$ be the plane curve obtained by projecting $C$ onto the tangent plane along the normal to the surface at $p$. Is it true that $\beta$ is also unit-speed?

This question raised when I try to solve another problem. I know the tangent vector of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ at $p$ are the same. But is it possible to find a neighborhood around $s_0$ such that $|\beta'(s)|=1$?

**My final goal is to show at $s_0$, $\beta'(s_0)\perp \beta''(s_0)$**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless $\alpha$ was planar to start with $\beta$ will not be arclength-parametrized. However, you should be able to argue that $|\beta'(s_0)|=1$, which is all you need. (Also, note that there are standard formulas for the curvature of non-arclength-parametrized curves.)

Comment: If I only have $|\beta(s_0)|$=1 at one point, can I take derivative and argue $\beta'' \perp \beta'$?

Comment: Argue that $|\beta'(s_0)|=1$ and $|\beta'(s)|\le 1$. Think about what you know about projection.

Comment: May you elaborate it more in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know other method to show $\beta''(s_0)\perp \beta'(s_0)$ except arguing $|\beta'(s)|$ is constant around a neighborhood of $s_0$. May you explain your method more?

Comment: You can write this out in formulas: $\beta'=\alpha'-(\alpha'\cdot n_0)n_0$, where $n_0$ is the unit normal of $S$ at $\alpha(s_0)$. So $|\beta'(s)|\le |\alpha'(s)|=1$. Since $|\beta'(s)|$ has a local maximum at $s_0$, $\beta'(s_0) \cdot \beta''(s_0) = 0$. (Differentiate $|\beta'(s)|^2$.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand what projection onto tangent plane means. Now it's clear.